# complex words indication

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

> Splicing factors have oncogenic properties. However, their expression patterns and practical priority in gastric cancer and the difference of them between gastric cancer and colorectal cancers are unknown.

I'm not a native  speaker. In the sentence, the intended meaning of "them" is "their expression patterns and practical priority".
If I use them, is it odd? What word should I use. If I use those instead of them, it it right? Please let me know the word (one word, if possible) that could indicate "their expression patterns and practical priority"

Answer (score 1):

Your first paragraph seems to have been written by a NNES. As far as I can understand it, the writer seems to mean:

Splicing factors have oncogenic properties. However, their expression patterns and practical priority in gastric cancer, and the differences between their action in gastric and colorectal cancer are unknown.

To me "**their** action" refers to **"splicing factors"**.

Comment: South Eastern Freight Lines??

Comment: @HotLicks Speaker of English as a foreign language.

Comment: Several acronym sites could not identify it.

Comment: @HotLicks  My bad. I should've been NNES.

Answer (score 1):

The expression 'the difference of them' is very odd in English and should be replaced by 'their difference'.

However neither of the above expresses your meaning because 'them' and 'their' refer to 'splicing factors'.

I suggest a complete rewrite of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your second sentence correctly -

> However, their differences in expression patterns and practical
>   priorities between gastric and colorectal cancers are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

" ...and differences thereof...."

thereof refers to whatever things were immediately preceeding.

No no no....   ignore that^^

After further review, I believe you are listing a series of things which are unknown.

However, their expression patterns, practical priority in gastric cancer, and the differences thereof in gastric cancer and colorectal cancers are unknown.

Maybe